# Error running express with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to start a very simple server on my Mac so I can access a file from localhost.

I have node and express installed and this is all that it is in my server file.

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/'));

app.listen(8080);

console.log("App listening on port 8080");
```

When I try to do:

```
node server
```

I get this as a response:

```
/Users/mt_slasher/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:47
var opts = Object.create(options || null)
                ^
TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: /
    at Function.create (native)
    at Function.serveStatic (/Users/mt_slasher/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:47:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mt_slasher/Desktop/My Projects/Basket/Site/server.js:4:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I've run this same file on a Windows machine with the same files and had no problem.

After some digging, I found this line seems to be the main culprit:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/'));
```

Can someone tell me what might be happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is because you are passing "/" as second parameter (options)

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

See serve-static:

```
function serveStatic(root, options) ...
```

https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js

Also note that it would be better to use a different directory than your root e.g. `express.static(__dirname + '/public')` to avoid exposing your root.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I also moved my static files to a different directory. It's weird that my code worked on my Windows machine and not my Mac. I think there must be different versions of a package under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

`express.static` is used to define directory where your "static" files reside look at [here for more info](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html).

It accepts only a string with the path you want to be static:

So your code should be:

```
app.use(express.static('/'));
```

Or

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

But that doesn't make much sense, imho.

Remove the line or define the real path where your assets files are.

Comment: I agree, that's why I wrote that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that page. I'm a front-end coder so I have scant knowledge of back-end and node, so it was helpful to get a little more info.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter you are passing to express.static is incorrect.  remove the second parameter.
app.use(express.static(__dirname));